# Can I avoid redundant segues when building tabbed interfaces

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have a storybord that has a `UITabViewController` serving four different tabs. Every tab has a navigation bar looking like this

[image: Navigation bar image]

All of the buttons do the exact same thing, but there are four tabs. I don't want to have to write code to handle touches on those buttons four different times. Is there a way to avoid this redundancy and without having to use any edgy hacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.
Way 1.
Create a base view controller, and make your 4 view controllers to inherit from it, and write all common code in that base view controller class.

Way 2. Combine your view controllers in the tab bar directly and embed the last one in a navigation controller.

Way 3.
Make a `UINavigationBar` subclass, add these buttons programmatically (and action methods also), and set it within the storyboard to all of your navigation controller's navigation bar.
Something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is combining `UINavigationController` with `UITabBarController`. Here is some example - you'll need one navigation controller and that it will be responsible for your navigation bar unchangable after changing the tab. Here it how's storyboard will look like:

[image]

And you can [download working project from here](https://bitbucket.org/Kettu/so_34358141)